# Clean way to disable form elements based on record

Tags: extjs

My record has boolean values (e.g. 'Editable'), and certain form fields should be disabled based on these values.

Is there a cleaner way than hidden fields which have a change listener, that disables form fields one by one based on newValue?

This is what I have:

```
xtype: 'hiddenfield',
name: 'Editable',
listeners:{
    change:function(field, newValue) {
        field.nextSibling('[name=Name]').setDisabled(!newValue);
        field.nextSibling('[name=Gender]').setDisabled(!newValue);
        ...
    }
```

but with right now eight different boolean values in the record, and some form fields disabled based on three of them, I am searching for a more convenient approach that I could somehow code directly into the field.

Comment: Why not use data binding?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Maybe because I don't know that it exists, what that is, or how it works. With that term, I have found an example [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/guides/quick_start/data_binding.html). I have made a simple fiddle based on that example but I didn't get data binding to work: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1vs7

Comment: Your fiddle is throwing error as record is not defined. Please update

Comment: @HarshitShah: Yes, that's exactly the problem I have with the example.

Comment: I am not getting you. What are you trying to get in that viewmodel as "record"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update form view model data like this

`form.getViewModel().set('record', record)`

and bind field value and disabled like this

```
{
    xtype:'textfield',
    name: 'Name',
    value: '',
    bind: {
        disabled: '{!record.Editable}',
        value: '{record.Name}'
    }
}
```

Check [this update](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1vsh) for you fiddle with data binding.

Answer (score 1):

Binding to the viewModel data is the solution you're looking for.
I adapted the fiddle from your comment a little bit to show you a working example of adding the record from your store to the viewModel of the form.
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1vuo

In addition to the form.loadRecord() call you make on your button, you'll also want to set the viewModel data to the same record:

```
{
    text: 'Load Homer',
    handler: function (btn) {
        var homerRecord = store.getAt(0);
        btn.up('form').loadRecord(homerRecord);
        btn.up('form').getViewModel().set('record', homerRecord);
    }
}
```

And with that you'll be able to reference the records fields on your components, specifically the `Editable` field you set:

```
viewModel: {
    data: {
        record: null
    }
},
items: [{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'Name',
    value: '',
    bind: {
        disabled: '{!record.Editable}'
    }
}]
```

If you have more complicated requirements for disabling your components, for example the field should be disabled based on some combination of two fields from the record, you can add `formulas: {}` to the viewModel.

For example, given the record:

```
{
    Name: 'Homer Simpson',
    Editable: false,
    butNotReally: true
}
```

Your viewModel could look like:

```
viewModel: {
    data: {
        record: null
    },
    formulas: {
        disableNameField: function (get) {
            return !get('record.Editable') && !get('record.butNotReally');
        }
    }
},
items: [{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'Name',
    value: '',
    bind: {
        disabled: '{disableNameField}'
    }
}]
```

This would disable the textfield if both `Editable` and `butNotReally` were false.

Answer (score 0):

```
{                                                                                
  xtype : 'numberfield',
  fieldLabel : 'Number of people'  
  allowBlank : false,
  disabled : record.get('isEnabled') // returns bool value
}
```

You can try disabled for each element.